# How to add multiple cloned divs to array in local storage and then delete each of those by clicking on toggle icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, local-storage

Every time I click on the ‘a' tag => (‘.favorite’).. I want to target the parent and add this whole div to an array. This ‘a’ tag contains an icon that will toggle between two classes as you can see in my code. When the heart is filled the parent will be cloned and added to a new tab => ‘#fav.’ However, as I said before I would also like to add this object to an array and then when the heart gets empty I would like to remove this object only from the existing array and keep all the other objects.

So basically, the problem is that I don't know how to do this. Store each object to the array in local storage and then remove each object from the array when needed as explained above.

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

HTML:

```
  <div class="box not-selected" id="box1">
    <a href="#" class="favorite"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box not-selected" id="box2">
    <a href="#" class="favorite"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box not-selected" id="box2">
    <a href="#" class="favorite"><i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="fav"></div>
```

JS:

```
$('.favorite').on('click', function(){

  var par = $(this).parents('.box');

  //TOGGLE FONT AWESOME ON CLICK
  if ($(par).hasClass('selected')) {
    par.find('.favorite i').toggleClass('fa-heart fa-heart-o');
  } else {
    par.find('.favorite i').toggleClass('fa-heart-o fa-heart');
  };

  // Clone div
  var add = $(this).parent().parent();
  add.each(function(){
    if (par.find('.favorite i').hasClass('fa-heart')) {

      var boxContent = ($(add).clone(true));
      var showHide = $(boxContent).find(".session").addClass('selected').removeClass('hidden-m');
      var get = $(boxContent).html();

      // Localstorage
      var temp = localStorage.getItem('sessions');

      // Array with cloned divs
      var tempArray = [];

      tempArray.push(get);

      var myJSONString = JSON.stringify(tempArray);

      var parseString = $.parseJSON(myJSONString);

      var finalString = myJSONString.replace(/\r?\\n/g, '').replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/^\[(.+)\]$/,'$1').replace (/(^")|("$)/g, '');

      var myJSONString = localStorage.setItem('sessions', finalString);

    } else if (par.hasClass('selected').find('favorite').hasClass('fa-heart-o')) {
      // remove div from array
    };

  });
});

// Append item if localstorage is detected
if (localStorage['sessions']) {
    $("#fav").append(tempArray);
};
```

Comment: What seems to be issue that you are facing. You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself well. I don't know if I'm pushing the objects to the array in a way that I can remove a certain object afterwards. So, as explained above when clicking on the 'a' tag it would add or remove the parent div from the array, depending on the toggle class. I hope it makes sense @DanPhilip

Comment: Have you worked out the pushing part, are the divs being pushed correctly to the array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the div from the array, following your workflow provided pushing works fine

```
 if (par.hasClass('selected').find('favorite').hasClass('fa-heart-o')) {
     var target = $(boxContent).html().replace(/\r?\\n/g, '').replace(/\\/g, '').replace(/^\[(.+)\]$/,'$1').replace (/(^")|("$)/g, '');;
     var targetArr = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('sessions'));
     var index = targetArr.indexOf(target);
     targetArr.splice(index,1);
     var targetString = JSON.stringify(targetArr);
     localStorage.setItem('sessions',targetString);         
 };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, just what I needed! @DanPhilip

Comment: @FranciscoFigueira Happy to help!